# Apache Spark - Java heap space error

Tags: scala, amazon-web-services, apache-spark

I have an apache spark application that does the following steps:

```
inputFile(#s3loc)
mapPartititions(mapper).groupByKey.mapPartitions(reducer).saveAsHadoopFile(params)
```

When I run this on a small data size it runs fine (around 100 files each one a gzipped 4k-5MB file). When the input size is large (same file size but 14k files) I get a java heap space error on `message.serialization` and `bytearray` and something of the sort.

I experimented a bit with my cluster (EMR) and for a cluster size of 60 m2.2x large machines each with 32 gigs of RAM and 4 cores I set the spark.default.parallelism=960 ie, 4 tasks per core. This threw the same error as above. When I changed this parallelism to 240 or 320 my tasks executed smoothly but it was pretty slow. What is causing this heap overflow? Most places that I have read up recommend around 3-4 tasks per core which should make 960 a good choice. How do I increase the number of tasks without causing a heap overflow?

Part of the logs (the latter end) can be found at : http://pastebin.ca/3078231

Comment: Strange indeed! I would expect more memory issues when you have _too few_ partitions (and they are too big). If you have _too many_ partitions, I would not expect OOMs, just slow performance. For some reason the opposite happens for you. I suggest you include in the question more details about the error. Which process suffers the OOM? The master or an executor? What is causing the OOM?

Comment: Could you provide a Shuffle size for some tasks from the Spark UI? Few largest values will be enough.

Comment: @DanielDarabos Would including the stack trace be helpful?

Comment: @rchukh I don't have the complete numbers with me right now. Ill have to run the job again for that but as I remember the shuffle size was smaller with more level of parallelism.

Comment: It seems that the driver has only `free: 265.1 MB`. Is it possible to make this value bigger?

Comment: Also, the `groupBy` can lead to OOM in case single 'key' group cannot fit in memory - [Spark best Practice](http://databricks.gitbooks.io/databricks-spark-knowledge-base/content/best_practices/prefer_reducebykey_over_groupbykey.html)

Comment: @rchukh I agree about the groupByKey but I dont think that should be the case here because it runs fine if the parallelism is set to something lower.

Comment: @Sohaib Maybe this [old email thread](http://apache-spark-user-list.1001560.n3.nabble.com/Driver-OOM-while-using-reduceByKey-td6513.html) will be helpful.

Comment: @rchukh "Why the workers send all the data back to driver to run reduceByKey? With the current implementation, if I use reduceByKey on TBs of data, that will be a disaster for driver. Maybe I'm wrong about the assumption of the spark implementation." This is the part I want answered I think.